# Accessing elements on a List of Lists

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I recently started to play with python/YAML and JINJA (No software experience) as I want to automate some task using Ansible.

The YAML representation is this, which as I understand is a list containing 2 other lists with some values inside them.

**YAML FILE**

```
VARIABLE_NAME:
  - LIST_1.1:
    - VALUE1
    - VALUE2

  - LIST_1.2: 
    - VALUE3
    - VALUE4
```

If my understanding is right this represents the following:

```
VARIABLE_NAME=[LIST1.1[VALUE1, VALUE2],LIST1.2[VALUE3, VALUE4]]
```

On the JINJA template, I want to loop and get LIST 1 VALUES to use for the first statement and list2 values for the 2nd statement. Something like this:

**JINJA TEMPLATE**:

```
{%for values in List1.List_1.1%}
Statement1 {values}
{% endfor%}

{%for values in List1.List_1.2%}
Statement2 {values}
{% endfor%}
```

What would be the correct syntax in this JINJA template to access the values in the YAML?. Additionally, is there a better way to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one in your template:

```
{%for values in LIST1['LIST_1.1']%}
Statement1 {{values}}
{% endfor%}

{%for values in LIST1['LIST_1.2']%}
Statement2 {{values}}
{% endfor%}
```

will give you this result:

```
Statement1 VALUE1
Statement1 VALUE2

Statement2 VALUE3
Statement2 VALUE4
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Hi, Arbab, thanks for your answer. I've just edited my question as it wasn't reflecting my actual issue. I've confirmed your solution works for the previous case but for this one I'm still unable to access the values in the nested lists.

In the JINJA template I'm trying the following:  <br/>
    '{% for ip in VARIABLE_NAME[RANGES][ip] %}' <br/>
    'statement1 {{ip}}` <br/>
    `{% endfor %}`  <br/>

But I still get back the following error in Ansible: `"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: list object has no element Undefined"`